# Could we stop by next week? vs. Could we stop by next week?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrasal-verbs

> 1. Could we stop by next week?

Does this mean "Can we stop what we are doing by next week", or does it only means "Can we stop by(visit) next week"?

Comment: It depends on the context! (BTW, it's _Does this mean A or_ **does it only mean** _B?_).

Comment: In *spoken* English, it could be understood as *Can we [**stop buy**](https://www.moneyland.ch/en/stop-buy-order-definition) next week?* Meaning *place an order to buy stocks or shares - **but only if the price reaches some specified level***.

Comment: In practice I think only the second one ("visit") is a natural interpretation.

Comment: Without context, it's impossible to answer. Context is King.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without additional context this is likely to be understood as "could we visit next week?" However, consider:

> I Think we have spent almost as much time on this project as it deserves. Could we stop by next week?

the meaning of "could we cease work by next week" is clear.

Tone of voice and pacing might also help clarify this, but the phrase "stop by" so often means "visit" that it is likely to be taken that way unless there is clear context making another meaning obvious.